# Correct way to write in pure CSS two effects with .active and :hover

Tags: html, css

I'm styling some links with the following CSS code, I named the links with the className 'nav-menu-link':

```css
.form-header {
    background-color: var(--background-color);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    transition: all .3s ease-out;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}

.form-logo {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.image-logo-container {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    width: initial;
    height: initial;
    background: none;
    opacity: 1;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.image-logo-container img {
    width: 250px;
    height: 52px;
}

.nav-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 100%;
}

.nav-menu {
    display: flex;
    font-size: 18px;
    width: 380px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100%;
    margin: unset;
}

.nav-menu-item {
    display: flex;
    height: 100px;
    align-items: center;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

.nav-menu-link {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
}

.nav-menu-link.active {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: var(--white);
}

.nav-menu-link:hover {
    color: var(--white);
    border-bottom: 2px solid var(--explorer);
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}


@media (min-width: 998px) {}

@media (min-width: 768px) {}
```

```html
<header class="form-header">
            <div class="nav-container">
                <a class="form-logo" id="navbar-link-form-logo" href="/">
                    <div class="image-logo-container">
                        <img src="https://placekitten.com/250/52" alt="" />
                    </div>
                </a>
                <nav class="container">
                    <ul class="row nav-menu">
                        <li class="nav-menu-item">
                            <a class="nav-menu-link active" href="/">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-menu-item">
                            <a class="nav-menu-link" href="/form">Form</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-menu-item">
                            <a class="nav-menu-link" href="/about">About</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <ul>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </header>
```

I did two effects, one is when the link is active with the '.active' class, and another is when I hover over the link with the 'hover'.

In pure CSS, the correct way to do these two effects is as I wrote in the code above?

Comment: Don't you want `:active`, not `.active`?

Comment: `transition: all .2s ease-in-out;` <-- Using `transition: all` is sloppy and can harm performance if you're inadvertently transitioning "expensive" properties (e.g. box dimensions causing a relayout) vs. "cheap" properties that only concern painting (e.g. `background-color`). Instead you should specifically name every property you intend to transition - and you might want to move the `transition` property to the "base" CSS rule because the `transition` property value will be cleared once `:hover` no-longer applies (i.e. it will result in instantaneous changes, not transitions).

Comment: Please post your HTML so we can reproduce it. Also, why are you using `display: flex` for what should normally just be a run-of-text? (this is why we **need** to see your HTML).